# I want to write a linked list and use it (via composition) to build a stack and a queue class

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

SO if I wanted to code the method Removelast(), would this work? this is for the linkedListDS Can I have a if without a else?

```
public E removeLast() {
    E result;          
    if(this.isEmpty())          
    {              
        System.out.println("No data present");              
         return null;          //over here
     }          

     result = tail.data;          
      if(this.size() == 1)          
        {               
           head= null;               
            tail= null;          
        }          
       else          
        {               
            Node<E> current;               
            current = head;                               
            while(current.next != tail)                   
                current= current.next;                                               

          tail = current;               
          tail.next=null;          
        }  

         return result;      
}
```

Comment: Sure, you can check the syntax for the if statement fairly easily on your own. Although, there are so many resources, if you're looking for an actual syntax exposition, use [Java Precisely](http://www.itu.dk/~sestoft/javaprecisely/javaprecisely-online.pdf). pg 42

Answer (score 0):

Using a if without else is correct. Note that there are different styles of programming out there. You might want to check out this classic book: [Code Complete: A Practical Handbook of Software Construction, Second Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670). I for myself use if only to partition the program flow that I dont have many top-level stand alone ifs (instead use 'else if').

You also have a problem in your code. If your list is empty (size() == 0) you try to walk the nodes, which should give you a null pointer exception.

Also if you have a linked list where each node stores a link to the previous node, you can remove tail by doing:

```
`Node<E> toRemove = tail;
tail = toRemove.previous;
if(tail == null) 
   head = null;
toRemove.previous = null;`
```